# vscode map user snippets to file extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode has the great feature of per-language user snippets (e.g. in `xml.json`).

*Is there a way to map those snippets to **file extensions**?*

My situation: I develop a lot of xml lately. We have roughly three xsd files and name instances of them with file extensions (so an instance of `foo.xsd` is named `my-instance.foo` rather than `my-instance.xml`). I build the most common parts as user snippets to save my time. However the different xsds create similar elements with different meanings (e.g. one creates `<foo bar="baz"/>`, one creates `<foo baz="bar"/>`), so defining a user snippet with prefix `"foo"` for the `xml` language would be ambique.

I could prefix the prefixes (creating e.g. `afoo` and `bfoo`), but this feels unnatural. Is there a better way to say "although both `foo`s belong to the xml language, one belongs to files of type `x` and one to `y`"?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code doesn't currently supoport different snippets per file extension that work on the same language.

But there is a hacky workaround for it by defining a separate language for `xsd`. Decide yourself if you want to do it. I tested it on Windows with version 0.8.0 (insider preview).

1. Go to the plugins folder of VSCode: `%CODE%\resources\app\plugins` and create a copy of `vs.language.xml`. Name the copied folder `vs.language.xsd`.
2. Open `vs.language.xsd` in VSCode.
3. Replace the content of `ticino.plugin.json` with

   ```
   {
       "pluginId": "vs.language.xsd",
       "activationEvents": ["textModel:xsd"],
       "mainModule": "./out/xmlMain",
       "contributes": {
           "language": [{
               "id": "xsd",
               "extensions": [ ".xsd", ".foo"],
               "firstLine" : "(\\<\\?xml.*)|(\\<svg)|(\\<\\!doctype\\s+svg)",
               "aliases": [ "XSD", "xsd" ],
               "mimetypes": ["text/xml", "application/xml", "application/xaml+xml"]
           }]
       },
       "scripts": {
           "compile": "node ../../node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile ../../gulpfile.plugins.js compile-plugin:vs.language.xsd"
       },
       "_bundling": [
           { "name": "./out/xmlMain" },
           { "name": "./out/xmlWorker" }
       ]
   }
   ```
4. Open to `xmlDef.json`. Change the value of `displayName` from `XML` to `XSD`. Change the value of `name` from `xml` to `xsd`.
5. List Replace the content of `xmlMain.js` with

   ```
   'use strict';
   define(["require", "exports", './xmlDef', 'monaco'], function (require, exports, languageDef, monaco) {
       function activate() {
           monaco.Modes.registerMonarchDefinition('xsd', languageDef.language);
           var myWorker = monaco.Modes.loadInBackgroundWorker(require.toUrl('./xmlWorker.js'));
           function format(resource, range, options) {
               return myWorker.then(function (w) {
                   var model = monaco.Services.ModelService.getModel(resource);
                   var value = range ? model.getValueInRange(range) : model.getValue();
                   if (value.length < 1024 * 1024) {
                       return w.beautify(value, {
                           indent_size: options.insertSpaces ? options.tabSize : 1,
                           indent_char: options.insertSpaces ? ' ' : '\t',
                           wrap_line_length: 256
                       });
                   }
                   else {
                       return null;
                   }
               }).then(function (result) {
                   if (result) {
                       return [{
                               range: range,
                               text: result
                           }];
                   }
                   else {
                       return null;
                   }
               });
           }
           monaco.Modes.FormattingSupport.register('xsd', {
               formatDocument: function (resource, options) {
                   return format(resource, null, options);
               },
               formatRange: function (resource, range, options) {
                   return format(resource, range, options);
               }
           });
       }
       exports.activate = activate;
   });
   ```
6. Restart VSCode. Now you are able to go to `File -> Preferences - User Snippets` and select the language `XSD`. You can define all `.xsd` and `.foo` related snippets here.

As I mentioned before: This is really hacky. The code highlighting looks slightly different in XSD files after applying this. If you don't like the result then you simply need to delete the folder `vs.language.xsd` and everything works like it did before.

Comment: Wow man, thanks for that insight into vscode. Bad that it doesn't support it out-of-the-box yet. I'll test it as soon as I find the time (and accept then, in the meantime I just upvoted your answer).